# File-server backup with multiple file-versions

Tags: backup, backup-restoration, file-server, time-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network-Backup-Software with file versioning and web-interface](https://serverfault.com/questions/105492/network-backup-software-with-file-versioning-and-web-interface)

Dear All,

I'm using a single Windows Server 2008 to share data between my WinXP and MacOSX - computers. There is one iSCSI - storage attached, which hold the windows-share. A second storage is attached and gets synchronized every hour.

The problem is, that if I delete or overwrite a file by accident I have no chance to restore this single file anymore. Further it is not possible to restore a specific version of a file.

What I would like to have:
All the data should be secured additionally on a further storage (which has much more capacity than the primary file-storage), where multiple versions of the files are saved. The number of file-versions to keep should be configurable. To restore a specific version of a file, there should be a web-interface which is accessible on my WinXP and MacOSX - machines. This web-interface should provide the same directory-tree, so that it is easy to find a file.

Does anyone of you know, which solution could fit my needs?

Best regards,
Daniel Lang

Comment: While not an exact duplicate this does appear to be a reworded version of http://serverfault.com/questions/105492/network-backup-software-with-file-versioning-and-web-interface

Answer (score 0):

It is not technically a backup and does fit all your expectations, but have you setup [Shadow Copies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) on your file server?  Your XP hosts will find that it is extremely simple to restore older files using this technology.  Just right click and go to the previous versions tab.

Comment: I though of sugessting shadow copies as well but the osx system won't be able to use them.